# How can I make a DropDownList invisible when a CheckBox is checked and vice versa

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Nothing is happening to the dropdownlist when i check the checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="false" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">


protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            DropDownList1.Visible = false;
        } 
    }
```

I want the dropdownlist to be visible when the checkbox is unchecked and be invisible when the checkbox is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" on your asp:Checkbox so the event is link with it.

```cs
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
```